# Undefined reference to class methods getValue() and operator<<

Tags: c++, class, header-files

I have a class `Card` implemented in a header file card.h and defined in card.cpp, I am trying to create two very simply methods, one is getValue(), which when called from the source program main.cpp should return one of the `Card` private members. And the other method is overloading the operator<< which I can do, but clearly not when doing the same in a header file. Here are the codes

main.cpp:

```
#include <fstream>
#include "header_files/card.h"
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void print_vec(vector<Card>* a);

int main()
{
  ifstream file("poker.txt");
  vector<Card> cards;
  string read;

  while(file >> read) //READ THE FILE 
    cards.push_back(read);
  file.close();

  cards[0].getValue();
  return 0;
}

void print_vec(vector<Card>* a)
{
  for(int i = 0; i<a->size(); i++)
    cout << a->at(i) << "\n";
}
```

card.cpp:

```
#include "./../header_files/card.h"
Card::Card(std::string& s)
{
  whole_card = s;
  int size = s.size();
  if( s[0] >= 50 && s[0] <= 57 ) //check if its 2-9
    value = s[0] - 48; //convert to actual value from ASCII
  else if( s[0] == 84 ) //ASCII equivalent of T (i.e. 10)
    value = 10;
  else{ //must be ACE or J,Q,K
    switch( s[0] ){
    case 'A':
      value = 14; break;
    case 'J':
      value = 11; break;
    case 'Q':
      value = 12; break;
    case 'K':
      value = 13; break;
    }
  }

  //NOW SET THE SUIT FOR THE CARD
  suit = s[1];

}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Card& e)
{
  os << e.whole_card << "\n";
  return os;
}

char Card::getSuit()
{
  return suit;
}

int Card::getValue()
{
  return value;
}
```

card.h:

```
#ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Card
{
  char suit;
  int value;
  std::string whole_card;
public:
  Card(std::string& s); //constructor prototype
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Card& e);
  char getSuit();
  int getValue();
};

#endif
```

However when I compile all the codes together I get the following error:

```
main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0xca): undefined reference to `Card::getValue()'
main.o: In function `print_vec(std::vector<Card, std::allocator<Card> >*)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x18c): undefined reference to `operator<<(std::ostream&, Card const&)'
```

I have looked over it a lot and I am not sure what to do at this point. I have only just started experimenting with header files and classes, so it is a bit messy.

Thank you

Comment: you are trying to push back string to a vector of Card in your main function

Comment: @IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII there is a converting constructor, thus this should work

Comment: Yes I am pretty sure that is not the issue

Comment: what would happen if you do Card(read).getValue();

Comment: it still results in same compilation error saying "undefined reference to `Card::getValue()`

Comment: you have else if( s[0] = 84 )  change it to else if (s[0] ==84), = is assignment and will return true

Comment: How do you compile exactly ?
(I'm thinking about forgetting compiling card.cpp)

Comment: @IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII Okay thank you it seems that fixed it! Actually to edit it seems that did not matter in the end i seems to work now all of a sudden...